# A random pattern with predefined style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern, random

I would like to create the following picture with Ti*k*Z. But I have no idea how to do this mathematically; for example, saying that if that condition is met, the rectangle, corresponding to the image, will turn and also get the color.

At the moment, I can only do it manually, that is, manually positioned and filled out.

With node:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=7pt] (a) {};
            \fill[orange] (a.north west) -- (a.south west) -- (a.south east) -- cycle;
            \fill[brown] (a.north west) -- (a.north east) -- (a.south east) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With usual options:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[orange] (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
        \fill[brown] (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the image:

[image]

(P.S. ignore the „wave“ in the picture – it has to be straight in a line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposal: create the elements of the pattern as `savebox`es (to decrease compilation time and avoid nesting `tikzpicture`s or a more complicated syntax), and use them in a random way, and also make random rotations by 90 degrees. Easy to generalize.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\newsavebox{\obbox}
\sbox\obbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
\fill[orange] (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1,0) -- cycle;%
\fill[brown] (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newsavebox{\owbox}
\sbox\owbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
\fill[orange] (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1,0) -- cycle;%
\fill[white] (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newsavebox{\bwbox}
\sbox\bwbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
\fill[brown!60] (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1,0) -- cycle;%
\fill[white] (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newsavebox{\dwbox}
\sbox\dwbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
\fill[brown!80!black] (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1,0) -- cycle;%
\fill[white] (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\drawbox}[1]{\ifcase#1%
\usebox{\obbox}%
\or%
\usebox{\owbox}%
\or%
\usebox{\bwbox}%
\or%
\usebox{\dwbox}%
\fi}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \X in {1,...,8}
    { \foreach \Y in {1,...,8}
     {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\randOne}{4*abs(rand)}
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\randFlip}{2*abs(rand)}
     \node[rotate={90*\randFlip}] at (\X,\Y) {\drawbox{\randOne}};
     }
     }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]